# Nodemailer and Oauth2 -- unhandled promise rejection error

Tags: oauth-2.0, nodemailer

I have been trying to get nodemailer to deliver rsvp responses to my email with the help of Oauth2.  I had short term success but then realized the access token needed to be refreshed constantly for Oauth2 to continue to work. So after trying suggestions from here:

[Google oauth 2.0 API password change Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174317/google-oauth-2-0-api-password-change-username-and-password-not-accepted/42292944#42292944)

...and following steps from here:  https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1

...I have found myself stuck with this unhandled promise rejection error:

(node:42384) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I don't know what else to try.  I've been searching for help for weeks.  Does anyone know how to fix this error?  I appreciate any help offered.  Thanks.